# JavaScript uploaded from static files APEX 4.2.4

Tags: javascript, oracle, file, static, oracle-apex

In which folder from the Oracle server are the JavaScript files stored uploaded from Shared Components - Static Files? I’m using APEX version 4.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from apex forum:

> the js files uploaded from "Shared Components - Static Files" are not stored in a folder, they are stored in the database.